# How to reply to a conversation with ConversationId if the conversation has been deleted?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Our service takes in feedback from users. If we want to reach out to them, we do that through Exchange via EWS. The replies from the customer are ingested into our system (disconnected from Exchange). If we need to reply, we find the last response via ConversatoinId and reply to that. I would like to set a retention policy (or manually clean up) so that Exchange items are cleaned up. I would like to be able to send a new message on the same conversation, if the need should arise, for a thread where the conversation has been deleted. It seems I can't do this, even if I have a conversationId (as that is read-only). Is there any way to reply to a conversation without having an EmailMessage from that conversation (i.e., a way to set the ConversationId and/of ConversationTopic manually)?

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you are storing the message in the external system eg if you exported it as an Eml/Mime if you wanted to reply you could reimport the message and then reply to the imported message.

You could also use something like MailKit and compose the reply in Mime so you can set all the conversation, inreply-to headers and then send that see [Reply to a Mail in Mailkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102698/reply-to-a-mail-in-mailkit)

Comment: Yes, but I am originally deleting due to user data retention. I don't have the full message. I am hoping to use the ConversationId / ConversationTopic to create a new message (within the MIME content), but have it be within the original thread.

Comment: You can try drafting the reply in Mime with the information you